# Bordes redondeados java fx

Tags: java, javafx

Quiero conseguir que los bordes de mis aplicaciones estén redondeados, como por ejemplo los del Mac Os, sin embargo el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado]

¿Cómo puedo eliminar el trozo blanco que queda en las esquinas de la  aplicación?

Este es mi código:

`Main class`:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Preview.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Ejemplo Drag And Drop");
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Y el archivo css:

```
.mainFxmlClass {
#pane{
    -fx-background-size: 800 900;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 18 18;
    -fx-border-radius: 0 0 18 18;
    -fx-border-width:5;
    -fx-background-color: #FC3D44;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes cambiar el color de relleno del objeto Scene a transparente, de este modo:

```
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

También deberás cambiar el estilo de la ventana a transparente, así:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

El problema es que, esta acción quita los bordes de la ventana, por lo que deberás crear los botones para: minimizar, maximizar y cerrar la ventana.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en: [ventana con bordes redondeados en JavaFX](https://acodigo.blogspot.com/2015/03/ventana-javafx-con-bordes-sombreados.html)

Comment: ¿Sabes por qué scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); me lo da como no aceptable y error?

Comment: Asegúrate de importar el paquete correctamente, debe ser: import javafx.scene.paint.Color